# ASP.Net making my html comments visible

Tags: asp.net, html, comments

In my page source I put: `<!-- A comment -------->`

and ASP.Net converts it to: `&lt;!-- A comment --------&gt;`

so by the time it gets to the browser, my comment is visible.

It doesn't do it to all comments and if I add in another comment it sometimes makes the comment go away.

Anyone seen this before? How can I fix it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try putting an space before `-->`. It guess this might help. I haven't had such a problem before though.

It's a good practice:

- **not to have -- in comments**
- **begin your comments with `<!--` without more dashes**
- **end your comments with `-->` without more dashes**

Comment: That does seem to help & I take the point about best practice and will follow that more carefully from now on but quite what ASP.Net is thinking of when deliberately converting the comments I don't know!

Comment: ASP.NET parser **does** care about HTML. It parses it on the server to some level. This is how it handles runat="server" tags.

Comment: Yep, I get that I guess I expected it to just ignore anything it doesn't understand. Global search and relace here I come.

Thanks for the response.

Comment: It's not just a matter of best practice: getting the wrong number of -- tokens in HTML as above (or in XML, using any -- other than -->) is invalid and can cause parsers (and even sometimes browsers) to choke. Avoid.

Answer (score 1):

Please check this page about [comments](http://htmlhelp.com/reference/wilbur/misc/comment.html) and see if it helps.

Answer (score 0):

Response.Write("`<!--`");

rest of html?

Resonse.Write("-->");